# rollback from paypal pro hosted_pro to paypal pro redirect in magento

Tags: magento, redirect, iframe, paypal

I have a problem on my magento installation.

An year ago we choosed to use PayPal Pro with iframe in our Magento 1.6.2.

After that we upgraded to Magento 1.7.2

At this moment we are trying to use redirect Paypal Pro solution due the fact that
iframe is not working well on mobiles.

But we are unable to find the setting to choose a "redirect" instead that a "iframe" in Paypal setting.

So when we disabled the old one page checkout cart, where the iframe was loaded, and installed a 
brend new one page checkout, we figured out that after clicking on the button "compleate purchase" instead of going to Paypal it goes directly on the Magento "purchase succes" page... and order is crated on Magento as pending payment.

Is there some place a config i must set to indicate to use the redirect method, instead of the iframe?

If not, is there a way to reinstall a fresh PAYPAL payment module ?

Comment: Payments Pro doesn't work with any redirect, so I'm a little confused.    Sounds like you're thinking of Express Checkout.  Both Express Checkout and Payments Pro are included with Magento by default, though, so it should just be a matter of disabling the Advanced module you're using and enabling the EC and Pro modules.

Comment: Dear Andrew, i am confused too. The PayPal email support told me to log in Paypal, and select from paypalpro one of the 3 Layouts : Layout A, B, or C.
The Layout C is the MiniLayout thay told me is iframe.
So they told me just to save it and set paypal pro in Magento.
I do it but is not bring me to this Paypal pages to make payment. Instead it goes directly on checkout success.

Comment: Paypal answered me back that they saw my checkout and figured out that Magento and Paypal module are not working. So, of course, problem is in the past customization that a company made on our magento.

Is there a way the download a new paypal module or upgrade this or grub it from another clean installation? Where can i find all file and folders of this module?